# Neighbourhood set in Graph theory

Tags: inequality, graph-theory

Let $G$ be any connected graph with $\Delta(G)$ be maximum degree. If $D \subseteq V(G)$ then how can we say that $\left | \bigcup \limits_{v \in D} N(v) \right | \leq |D| \Delta(G)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\left|\bigcup_{v \in D} N(v)\right|
  &\leq \sum_{v \in D} |N(v)| \\
  &= \sum_{v \in D} \deg_G(v) \\
  &\leq \sum_{v \in D} \Delta(G) \\
  &=|D|\cdot\Delta(G)
\end{align}

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$